# Question about Lagrange method for reducing quadratic forms

Tags: linear-algebra

I know how this works. But I am quite curious about why it works. Why does using the Lagrange method always get a non-degenerate transformation?
i.e.

for a quadratic form, $X^TAX$, why using the Lagrange method, we can always get a non-singular matrix $C$, after the transformation $X=CY$, we can reduce the quadratic form.

For example, If I have $(x+y)^2+(y-z)^2+(x+z)^2$,
we can not let $x'=x+y,y'=y-z,z'=x+z$ because $C$ is singular.
However, if we use the Lagrange method.

we can get $x'=\sqrt2 x+\frac{\sqrt2}{2}( y+z),y'=\frac{\sqrt 6}{2}(y-z),z'=z$. In this scenario, $C$ is non-singular

Comment: Is it enough to say that A is symmetric, and that every symmetric matrix is diagonalisable?

Comment: No. To make it clearer, I add more details to the original question.

Comment: Could be what you are calling Lagrange method: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr